# Oracle PL/SQL - Inserting values based on max of columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to insert data (product, timestamp) into a table xyz from tables A, B & C with a primary key as PRODUCT. All the three table have a timestamp column along with other columns. I want to insert row with product and max of timestamp of these three tables (A, B & C).

Comment: You should show what you have tried so far, why it does not work.. don't throw your question out and expect people to make the query for you

Comment: Could you please add more details like an example of desired result ; Source table data examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify what you want to happen if product already exists in table xyz, so on the assumption that it doesn't, you could use a query like this:

```
Insert into XYZ(Product, Timestamp)
Select Product, max(timestamp)
  from (select product, timestamp from a union all
        select product, timestamp from b union all
        select product, timestamp from c)
 group by product
```

Comment: He wants to get MAX timestamp of all tables, meaning 3 records with the max of each table (A, B and C).

Comment: No The OP stated that Product is Primary Key of table XYZ therefore only one Product record, and Max timestamp across all three tables, A, B, and C.  Please remove your -1.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following:

```
INSERT INTO xyz
  ( product, timestamp )
SELECT MAX(product) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY timestamp DESC ) AS product
     , MAX(timestamp)
  FROM a
 UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(product) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY timestamp DESC ) AS product
     , MAX(timestamp)
  FROM b
 UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(product) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY timestamp DESC ) AS product
     , MAX(timestamp)
  FROM c;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATED** as per Sentine's comment:

Try this (syntax not verified):

```
INSERT INTO xyz (product , timestamp) 
 (
    SELECT product , MAX(A.timestamp) 
      FROM A
    UNION
    SELECT product , MAX(B.timestamp) 
      FROM B
    UNION
    SELECT product , MAX(C.timestamp) 
      FROM C
) ;
```

Comment: You can't insert 4 columns from the subquery into just two columns in the destination table like that.

Comment: @Sentinel, rRe-thinking